# network path not found error for local machine

Tags: c#

I am testing an application on my local machine to create a file. The network path I have set for testing to `\\127.0.0.1\NEWFILE\test1.txt`.  I am getting "network path not found" error message. What could be the problem?

```
filePath = @"\\127.0.0.1\NEWFILE\test1.txt";
File.WriteAllText(filePath, Contents.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
filePath = @"\\127.0.0.1\NEWFILE\test1.txt";
File.WriteAllText(filePath, Contents.ToString());
```

Notice the extra backslash.

EDIT 1
Is NEWFILE a share on your machine that your program has write permissions to?

EDIT 2
Confirm that NEWFILE is a share on your machine.
Open Windows Explorer and in the address bar type \\127.0.0.1\

After you type the last backslash a list of accessible shares should appear.  If NEWFILE is not one of them, then that's your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: @nav100: Obviously your network path doesn't exist. Have you double-checked if it really does?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add another slash at the beginning.  UNC paths with the server name start with two slashes:

```
@"\\127.0.0.1\NEWFILE\..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the NEWFILE share is setup properly:

This should work, but will be the file "test1.txt" in the NEWFILE share, not a newfile folder on C:\.

```
filePath = @"\\127.0.0.1\NEWFILE\test1.txt";
```

Answer (score -1):

Check Whether the **Server Services** Which Supports file sharing, print and named Pipe sharing over the the network is enabled. You can Find this Service under Administrative tools/Services .I had a similar problem While adding User Accounts  to a local machine .